# Is it possible to track the origin of an app install on iOS or Android?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter, conversion-tracking

In their ad campaign administration screens, Twitter and Facebook both report "installs" as results. But I don't think there's a way to know that a user actually *installed* an app after following a Facebook or Twitter link to that app's page on its platform's app store. Am I wrong? Or by "installs" do they mean "visits to your app's store page"?

Comment: Facebook uses the Facebook SDK to verify that the user actually install and even started the app

Comment: @WizKid I'm quite curious about how it's possible to know the origin of an iOS app install programmatically. Do you put URL params on the link to the App Store, and do those make it somehow into the installation? Or do you use some sort of device ID to track that this device tapped a link within the FB app to this app store page and then opened the same app a little while later for the first time?

Comment: There is no way to know if a user came from Facebook and that is on purpose. Facebook will give you aggregated statistics but not per user

Comment: @WizKid So what is specifically meant by the "installs" count in the FB campaign admin screens?

Comment: It is number of unique users that started the app.

Comment: @WizKid so it's not correlated to interactions with ads?

Comment: People that click on an ad an then start the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102718/discussion-between-tom-hamming-and-wizkid).